# Force acting on parallel and in series springs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring

How to prove from Newton laws that same force acts on both springs that are connected in series and it is equal to the total force?

How to prove from Newton laws that total force acting on parallel connected springs is equal to the sum of forces acting on each spring?

**addition:** 
I will paraphrase core ideas of ja72's answer. The main trick is to think about a spring as two points interacting with each other and about the Hook's law as a law describing interaction between these two points in the same way the Columb`s law describes interaction between two charges. The hardest part is to abstract from thinking about  a spring. First, consider that by Newton's third law the forces acting on these two points are pointing in opposite directions, but their modules are equal. Next, consider that the  point where springs are connected is not mowing, so by Newton's first law F1 is equal to F2.

Shortest answer: think about springs the same way as about interacting charges, only with Hook's law describing interaction.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I have a bachelor degree at chemistry. I was trying to renew school physics. I have understanding of calculus. As far I understand all mechanics should be derivable from Newtons laws and properties of vectors. Posted question is part of problem that I can't understand. I saw explanation for my problem (bigger one) there weren't mentioned  answer on my to questions. It seems that author thought that it is self evident. I don't understand why it should be self-evident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one case (series) all the springs share the same force but have varying deflections.

[image: pic]

Use $x_i = \frac{F_i}{k_i}$ for $ i=1 \ldots 3$ to get the total deflection

$$ x = \frac{F_1}{k_1} + \frac{F_2}{k_2} + \frac{F_3}{k_3} = ( \frac{1}{k_1} + \frac{1}{k_2} + \frac{1}{k_3} ) \, F $$

In the other case (parallel) all the springs share the same deflection but have varying forces.

[image: pic]

Use $F_i = k_i x_i$ for $i=1\ldots 3$ to get an expression for the total force

$$ F = k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2 + k_3 x_3 = (k_1 + k_2 + k_3)\, x $$

Comment: I did that. You just paraphrased my question. I don't understand.

Comment: It is pretty straight forward. See edit to answer to see how to do it from the diagrams.